# Getting issue in tomcat 7 but worked on tomcat 5. (Failed to start component )

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat7, tomcat5.5

My application was running fine on tomcat 5.5 but now i want to use tomcat 7.I am getting issue if i use tomcat 7.

I found on net and saw that people getting this issue. But i am facing this issue on tomcat 7 but on tomcat 5 my application was working fine.

Any clue ?

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEng
ine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/ServiceDefinitionApp]]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:904)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:618)`

ADDITON after comments :

`Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.alc.alcml.jaxb.xjc.Attributetype
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at com.container.AppClassLoader.findClass(AppClassLoader.java:98)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)`

As a solution i added the jar which contains this file in my application WEB-INF/lib and all worked fine.

NOW Question :

when i was running on tomcat 5.5, same application was running fine without having a jar in WEB-INF/lib.Why ?

Please make a note that JAR is available in class-path from some other directory but this is applicable same for tomcat5.5 and tomcat 7.

Comment: That doesn't look like a complete stacktrace to me ...

Comment: Add completes stack trace in post

Comment: @StephenC and Gk - I have updated it.Please see.

Answer (score 0):

I can't give you a definite answer, but one possible explanation is that the JAR file was in the "shared libraries" directory of your Tomcat 5.5 installation.